# Is it possible to show the alias command before being executed?

Tags: alias

Let’s say I have the following alias defined:

```
alias agi='sudo apt-get install'
```

When I execute `agi` I would like to see `sudo apt-get install` displayed before the command is run.  This would serve as a reminder of what is actually being done.  Is there a way to make this happen?

Comment: [The answer in this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1139470/echo-the-alias-command-before-running-it) might give you what you’re looking for 

Comment: Well, the bash -x (set -x) will do the trick for showing the alias expansion, but unfortunately, all commands get echoed, whether or not aliased.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way you can do it.  I am certain there are more ways than one to do it.

```
alias agi='echo "sudo apt-get install"; sudo apt-get install'
```

Comment: Very good suggestion!