# apt install <> = "Configuration item specification must have an =<val>"

Tags: apt

Im getting this error "Configuration item specification must have an =" after `apt install snapd`. Apparently I have two versions available:

```
snapd/focal-updates,focal-security,now 2.54.3+20.04.1ubuntu0.2 amd64 [residual-config]
snapd/focal 2.44.3+20.04 amd64 [residual-config]
```

I'm a bit surprised there is nothing on Google for this error. I'm sure just need to enter a version with the =val, but not sure how yet.

Answer (score 0):

From `man apt`, "install pkg [{=pkg_version_number.." and "A specific version of a package can be selected for installation by following the package name with an equals (=) and the version of the package to select."

I'm assuming no space, but I still get the same error with putting `apt install snapd=anything`. I'm going to try to remove the plain focal repo from sources.list, but that isnt a good solution.

I commented out the main focal repo line. I am using UbuntuAdvantage cips which has extra source lists in the source.list.d dir. Removing just the main focal repo, makes `apt list` only one version. However, I still get the same error.

Okay, that is strange. I had a hunch it could be from my apt alias (which is `alias apt='sudo apt '` so I don't have to type `sudo` every time) and sure enough it succeeded. I don't know why.

Putting `\` before any alias will unalias it.

Comment: Having a space at the end of an alias like in `alias apt='sudo apt '` means that the next work is considered for alias expansion too (so the `install` in `apt install ..` is also expanded as an alias. Have you also made an alias for `install`? Use `set -x; apt install ...; set +x` to see what bash runs exactly.

Comment: @muru, thanks.. yes, the space is on purpose. I just found I added one for install because it allows mv'ing into a dir while keeping the target ownership and perms, and it has the commands necessary for that in the alias. I'll have to make a different name for it.. thanks that was a very intuitive insight! (maybe I'll alias mv to install, cant see why not).. btw, running `alias` shows them all.. and the space is so I can use aliases to common directories.. I can type `vi fstab` and it will run `vi /etc/fstab` I also have one for `cat sources` will then be `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: Then I'd suggest removing the space in the apt alias, since there are only a limited set of subcommands for apt, and you're unlikely to pass in directories as the first argument to apt.

Comment: @muru thanks, i considered being more selective about the spaces.. i added them to about 50 aliases in bulk.. i think my mistake was being so excited there was a builtin command for moving files without changing ownership, like to root.. as I am often "sudo -s'd" into. I wonder if there are permissions for directories that forbid allowing different ownership inside. Still `mv` should do this by default, or at least have a flag for it I could alias, in my opinion. So many Ubuntu users, only have one user and have to use root to manipulate so many things as root.

Comment: another idea would be to have an option to show the unaliased command before it runs.. which someone has posted here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1139470/echo-the-alias-command-before-running-it.. or showing the full expanded command in the history.. I might have to add `type <alias>; ..` to all of them.. or it looks like there might be a shopt setting.

Answer (score 0):

As you've already identified, installing a specific version is generally done like this:

```
sudo apt install {package}={version}
```

So, to install `snapd` version `2.54.3`, you would do this:

```
sudo apt install snapd=2.54.3
```

If you continue to receive errors, you may want to first deal with the `[residual-config]` messages that are part of your listing to ensure that some residual configuration files are not creating problems for the new installation.

Comment: it turns out it was related to an alias.. getting the exact same error after I tried adding multiple versions after = in multiple formats led me to suspect it wasnt related to the version.. the residual-config has to do with that Im trying to move /snap dir to a partition.